# Testing navigate (react-navigation) call after timeout in useEffect Hook with Jest

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs, react-navigation, react-hooks

I have a functional component that navigates to another component after a set timeout. This is made in the useEffect Function.

**Component**

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';

const Startup: React.FC<> = props => {
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      props.navigation.navigate('Signup_Signin');
    }, 3000);
  });

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Startup View</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default Startup;
```

**Here is the test for it**

```
import 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import { create } from 'react-test-renderer';
import Startup from '../../../src/views/Startup';
// Note: test renderer must be required after react-native.

const createTestProps = (props: Object) => ({
  navigation: {
    navigate: jest.fn(),
  },
  ...props,
});

describe('<Startup />', () => {
  const StartupView = create(<Startup {...createTestProps()} />);
  test('Matches the snapshot', () => {
    expect(StartupView.toJSON()).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
  test('Navigation called with Signup_Signin', () => {
    jest.useFakeTimers();
    jest.advanceTimersByTime(3000);
    expect(StartupView.root.props.navigation.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
      'Signup_Signin',
    );
  });
});
```

I first test that the component matches its snapshot which passes without a problem.
I then create a fake timer and advance it to the same timer as set in the component. I can then verify if the navigate prop has been called.

**Jest Error message**

> ●  › Navigation called with Signup_Signin
>
> ```
> expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)
>
> Expected: "Signup_Signin"
>
> Number of calls: 0
>
>   25 |     jest.useFakeTimers();
>   26 |     jest.advanceTimersByTime(3000);
> > 27 |     expect(StartupView.root.props.navigation.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
>      |                                                        ^
>   28 |       'Signup_Signin',
>   29 |     );
>   30 |   });
> ```

It appears that that the prop is never called. I have checked through my app and the navigation is actually made. I am guessing the problem comes from how i describe the test.

Answer (score 0):

`it` internal' allows you to check if a certain value is what we `expected`.

However, the function moving the screen does not have a value to check because there is no result return value.

The test can be carried out as follows:

```js
it('Navigation called with Signup_Signin', () => {
  jest.useFakeTimers();
  setTimeout(() => {props.navigation.navigate('Signup_Signin');}, 3000);
  jest.runAllTimers();
});

// OR

it('Navigation called with Signup_Signin', (done) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    props.navigation.navigate('Signup_Signin');
    done();
  }, 3000);
});
```

Comment: I don't see why I have to manually execute the navigate function in the test since i want to verify that it is automatically executed within the component hook.

Answer (score 0):

`useEffect` is not called synchronously when render happens. In SSR, it's not called at all. Have you verified that `useEffect` is called at all in your tests by putting a `console.log`?

I'd suggest to use something like https://github.com/callstack/react-native-testing-library for testing which automatically handle things like this.

Also worth re-thinking the tests. It seems like it's testing implementation details.